# Creating portable Matlab

Tags: matlab, portable-applications

I would Like to create a Portable MATLAB Application from the existing installation. Anyone please provide info regarding this, i.e., How to create Portable MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need the [*Matlab Compiler*](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/compiler/).

Comment: NO.. sorry for misunderstanding. Please check the following link you will come to know what i want. http://everything-free-download.blogspot.in/2011/10/matlab.html

Answer (score -1):

You are not allowed to make Matlab portable. (To be completely sure, you can refer to the EULA of your Matlab installation)

> Commercial licenses, as a general rule, do not permit you to alter an
>   application in any way or redistribute it.

source:http://portableapps.com/development/beginner_packaging

Making an application portable counts as "altering" it.

In case you need to make another app portable, the [PortableApps launcher](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/portableapps.com_launcher) can do the job.

Additionally, you can check out a portable Matlab alternative, called FreeMat.